# Finding a value for c which allows the antiderivative to go through the origin?

Tags: integration, derivatives

This problem most likely has to do with the second fundamental theorem of calculus (SFTOC), but I do not understand why the answer is what it is:

> Given $f$ is a continuous odd function, and $F$ is another function
>   defined as
>
> $F(x)=\displaystyle\int_{-12}^{x}f(3t-c)dt$
>
> what values of $c$ will make $F$ and $F'$ go through the origin?
>
> (question paraphrased)

I really don't understand why the answers are $c=-18$ and $c=0,$ respectively. I don't see how it fits the SFTOC either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$F(x)=\int_{-12}^x f(3t-c)dt$$
Using integration by substitution, we can take $t\to t/3$ to get
$$F(x)=\frac{1}{3}\int_{-36}^{3x} f(t-c)dt$$
and $t\to t+c$ to get
$$F(x)=\frac{1}{3}\int_{-36-c}^{3x-c} f(t)dt$$
Now consider $F(0)$:
$$F(0)=\frac{1}{3}\int_{-36-c}^{-c} f(t)dt$$
If the function $F$ passes through the origin, we have that
$$F(0)=0$$
$$\frac{1}{3}\int_{-36-c}^{-c} f(t)dt=0$$
This happens in two cases. The first is when the starting and ending points of the integral are equal, and the second is when they are opposites (since $f$ is odd). Thus we have that either
$$-36-c=-c$$
or
$$36+c=-c$$
The first option cannot happen, and the second occurs when $c=-18$.

Now we shall solve the second part of the problem: since
$$F(x)=\frac{1}{3}\int_{-36-c}^{3x-c} f(t)dt$$
then
$$F'(x)=f(3x-c)$$
If we want $F'$ to pass through the origin,
$$F'(0)=0$$
and so
$$f(-c)=0$$
Since $f$ is odd, this $f(0)=0$, so this will definitely occur when
$$-c=0$$
or
$$c=0$$.

Comment: I understood almost all of it, except for when you said near the end "Since f is odd, this f(0)=0, so this will definitely occur when -c=0". Does this imply that all odd functions go through the origin? Thanks for the answer to the first part to the question

Comment: Yes, all odd functions go through the origin. If $f$ is odd, then
$$f(x)=-f(-x)$$
which implies
$$f(0)=-f(0)\implies f(0)=0$$.